# Linq equality comparing not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Given this method:

```
internal static IEnumerable<Entity> GetByParentImpl<Entity, TKey>(this ICanGetByParent<Entity, TKey> self, TKey parentId, string fieldName) 
    where Entity : class 
{
    RepositoryBase<Entity> rb = (RepositoryBase<Entity>)self;
    rb.unitOfWork.Begin();

    var entities = rb.unitOfWork.Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
        .Where(e => EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(GetId<Entity, TKey>(e, fieldName), parentId))
        .List();

    return entities;
}
```

And this helper:

```
private static TKey GetId<Entity, TKey>(object obj, string fieldName) where Entity : class
{
    TKey id = default(TKey);

    switch(id.GetType().Name) {
        case "Int32":
            break;
        case "Guid":
            id = (TKey)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TKey)).ConvertFromInvariantString((string)typeof(Entity).GetField(fieldName).GetValue(obj));
            break;
    }

    return id;
}
```

I'm getting this exception on my linq statement:

> Unrecognised method call:
>   System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]:Boolean Equals(System.Guid,
>   System.Guid)

What does this mean? I'm not even sure how to debug this correctly. I could have sworn that the code above was working...

Comment: I don't really know about linq-to-nhibernate, but from an entity-framework background I'd suspect that the query provider has no translation for the Equals method. You'll have to use an expression or do it in linq-to-objects.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do comparison in such way for linq to any database provider. Provider cannot transform this into expression tree. So you must use it after .ToArray() or give an  `Expression<Func<RegisterCardBase, bool>>` into Where instead of lambda.

PS: Why are you doing so strange actions with Guid? How it is storaged in database?

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate's Linq provider tries to convert the Linq query to HQL and eventually to SQL. The lambda expression you have in your Where method is not supported by default in NHibernate.

However, the NHibernate Linq provider is [extensible](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html). You can [create](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception) your own [extensions](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-customize-linq-provider-user-defined-sql-functions) for handling various unsupported expressions.

[Alessandro Giorgetti](http://www.primordialcode.com/) has a good sample on how to extend Linq provider to support [`String.Equals` with `StringComparison` option](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/linq-to-nhibernate-string.equals-with-stringcomparison-option).

**Edit**

I just realized that you are using QueryOver, and not NHibernate Linq. You should probably remove [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) tag. My answer is somewhat relevant if you switch to `session.Query<Entity>()`. Still, you might reconsider your approach for converting `Id` and using it in `Where`.

Comment: So instead of extending the linq provider, what would be a better approach to comparing the Guids?

Comment: @TylerWright Well, since you have only two types, you could just do separate queries... `if (typeof(TKey) == typeof(Guid)) <guid query> else <int32 query>`.